# Ninja Forms / File Upload issue after site migration

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, upload, ninja

I've got a Wordpress site with a Ninja form that's using a file upload add-on. The form was working just fine on my Godaddy staging server. I migrated the site to another Godaddy account and the form stopped working. Being that the hosting accounts, and all other configuration, were virtually identical, I was stumped to understand what the problem could be.

Then I checked the PHP error logs and saw the following:

```
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): No such file or directory in /new/server/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms-uploads/.../pre-process.php on line 203
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/OLD/server/wp-content/uploads/ninja-forms/tmp/xEgbu/ninja_forms_field_3332): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /new/server/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms-uploads/.../pre-process.php on line 209
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpqrLDo5' to '/OLD/server/wp-content/uploads/ninja-forms/tmp/xEgbu/ninja_forms_field_3332' in /new/server/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms-uploads/.../pre-process.php on line 209
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /new/server/wp-content/plugins/ninja-forms-uploads/.../processing/process.php on line 154
```

(FYI: the ellipsis is just a shorthand for unimportant parts of a file path.)

The thing to notice is the `new/server/` and `OLD/server/` conflict on the second and third PHP Warnings. For some reason, a Ninja Form script is attempting to move a file from a location on the old server to a location on the new server.

Is it possible that Ninja Forms, upon the initial installation, saved the full path of the server as a reference point in the database? If so, can that be found and adjusted without reinstalling Ninja Forms?

Thanks!
Mark

Comment: probably some config file with the old paths in it, search for that

Answer (score 1):

I suffered this too.

As at the end of https://ninjaforms.com/docs/file-uploads/

> If you migrate from another server and the File Uploads path is
>   pointing to the older server location, you can deactivate then
>   reactivate your File Uploads and Ninja Forms plugins to reset the file
>   path.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. And while the suggested steps (of deactivating and reactivation File Uploads and Ninja Forms plugins by fiorebat) might have had some role to play but it didn't resolve the issue for me.

The problem was a really really silly thing .. UTF/Charset encoding issue. To solve that, actually type in `%` and/or any special characters on the Upload settings section of the File Uploads plugin.

I suspect this happens when both WP have different charsets.

Background: We were using a custom path/destination for File Uploads with `%year%/%Mmonth%` in the path. When we hardcoded the path to say `2019/7` it worked fine. So next, we manually typed in `%` (or copy from the samples show on the same page) and it custom/dynamic paths worked as well.

Comment: Your answer is a bit difficult to understand, because the solution is drawn in a lot of text. I would suggest you highlight more clearly what is your proposed solution for the problem.